# MongoDB .NET: Converting Json to BsonArray

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a Json file looked like this

```
{
"CompanyStructure":{
"Version": 1,
"Structure_base":{
   "Employee": "Emp_ID",
   "Jobs": "Job_ID",
   "Contacts": "Contact_form"
                    },
"Structure_1":{
    "Employee": "xyz",
    "Jobs": "1",
    "Contacts": "Home"
              },
"Franchise_X":{
     "Number": "100",
     "Location": "NY",
     "Price": "100k",
     "Clients": "Crowded"
              },
}
etc etc
```

Above is basically a Json file, but I can't deserialize it into BsonArray in order to make a list and put in the database/colletion
Here is my code trying to deserialize it

```
string json_data;
using (var json_reader = new JsonReader(json_data))
            {
                var serializer = new BsonArraySerializer();
                BsonArray bsonArray = serializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(json_reader));
                foreach (BsonValue value in bsonArray)
                {
                    collection.InsertOne(value.AsBsonDocument);
                }
            }
```

I will always get the Error: "Can't deserialize BsonDocument to BsonArray".
Please help me with it. Thank you

Comment: after `"Version": 1,` the structure seems to be an array, but the Json have no such form. It should be `[{ "Structure_base":{...} }, { "Structure_1":{...}, ...]`

Comment: I know, but it really is a Json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array, your JSON data should be between square brackets. (`[`...`]`)

You can try this.

```
var json_reader = new JsonReader("[" + json_data + "]"))
```

Comment: This could help, but it will input everything in one document, not separate documents. Is there any way to put them in separated documents?

Comment: you need some string operation. this will work. `json_data = json_data.Substring(json_data.IndexOf(@"""Version"": 1,") + 13 )
                            .Replace("}}", "}")
                            .Replace("},", "}},{");
            json_data = String.Concat("[{", json_data, "]");`

Comment: Here is what I got: 

`'JSON reader was expecting ':' but found '": {
    "'.'`